# Symfony 4 fetch response.text() is the HTML for the profiler toolbar instead of json

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When fetching data, sometimes, my app will return the html for the debug toolbar.  What makes this quite bizarre, is that it does NOT happen every time.  I had to refresh the page 7 times for it to happen. In some cases it does it all the time.

When I turn off the profiler, there is no problem fetching the data.

I tried to switch to jQuery ajax, but I got the same type of results.

I am using the symfony server, symfony 4.2, php7.2, webpack encore, React js.

If I use postman to connect to the api, then I have no failures.  Only from the web page doing ajax.

I stripped down to putting the js code directly into the twig file to bypass Webpack.

I am looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

I checked the logs and it looks like the matched route is wrong.

```
Jul 17 15:44:48 SERVER GET  (200) /api/map-point/list/quick/26.190096/-80.365865
Jul 17 15:44:48 REQUES Matched route "_wdt". method="GET" request_uri="https://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/3de748
```

Comment: More strange... If the fetch function is executed twice, both calls are successful and retrieve the data.  If I remove 1, then problems start again.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple causes for this behavior.

My first guess is this could be caused by a missing/incorrect `Accept` header.
Without the header symfony might think you're requesting an html-page and add the toolbar's html to the response.

Open the network panel of your browser and check if the `Accept: application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json` headers are present in the (XHR-)Request you're sending to your application and in the response.

Further you could try to configure the profiler to collect data only for master requests or not. Try both configurations.

```
framework:
  profiler:
    only_master_requests: true # (default: false)
```

([Framework Configuration - Profiler - #only-master-requests](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#only-master-requests))

Make sure to clear your cache afterwards.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and added an Accept: application/json header.  I already had the content type. It didn't work.  but thank you.  Also, I use the subrequests on the profiler a lot, so that would not be ideal.

Comment: Okay my guess was you might have `only_master_requests` enabled and some of the requests might be classified as sub-requests. The `Accept` header is best-practice and my guess here was that postman would add it but your Ajax-request wouldn't. Do you have any requests listeners that conditionally enable the profiler in your application? If you don't want to spend too much time on the issue and you can isolate the routes with this behavior you can try to disable the profiler in the controller as shown [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/profiler/matchers.html). Not a nice solution though.